# ASP.net; automatically generated .js classes cannot be altered in their base files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am working on something that totally baffles me. In my ASP.net project, I have this file:

[image]

It goes by the name of base.js and is a mere 4214 lines long.
If I hit debug in my app, then suddenly, a new folder appears in within my solution that goes by the name of "script documents", and looks like this:

[image]

At the very bottom , you see a little file called: base.js.

This file is an exact copy of my base.js from "earlier".

Now, I can even make stop points inside this automatically generated file and they work!

But if I now were to make changes to the base.js file (the OG one), none of the changes are transmitted to the auto generated file.
I guess this has something to do with the version code, but I couldnt really figure out how that works.

How can I alter these auto generated script files?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello, what framework does your front end apply? Or what scaffolding tool was used?

Comment: I managed to solve it myself. By updating a constant value in the version number, a new file was generated, now with my code changes. I dont know why it works like that but in the end, all was fine. thanks!